# How to store object in a struct

Tags: json, struct, go

I'm not sure how to create a `struct` to store a JSON object that is being posted to my API.

The JSON looks like this:

```
{ 
    "name" : "Mr Robinson",
    "email" : "test@test.com",
    "username" : "robbo123",
    "properties" : {
        "property1" : "a property",
        "property2" : "another property"
    },
    "permissions" : ["perm1", "perm2", "perm3"]
}
```

There can be any number of `properties` and the `permissions` array can contain any number of values.

I am using this to decode the posted values:

```
err := json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(my_struct)
```

So far my struct looks like this:

```
type User struct {
    Name      string      `json:"name"`
    Email     string      `json:"email"`
    Username  string      `json:"username"`
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `map[string]string` for the properties and a `[]string` slice for the permissions:

```
type User struct {
    Name        string            `json:"name"`
    Email       string            `json:"email"`
    Username    string            `json:"username"`
    Properties  map[string]string `json:"properties"`
    Permissions []string          `json:"permissions"`
}
```

Output (wrapped):

```
{Name:Mr Robinson Email:test@test.com Username:robbo123 
    Properties:map[property1:a property property2:another property]
    Permissions:[perm1 perm2 perm3]}
```

Try the complete runnable app on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/JHqOd-me65).